# Brazilian Mathematical Olympiad 2023, Level U, Problem 3

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

#### Question

Prove that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that, for any integers $m, n$ with $n \geq m > 1$ and any real number $x > 1$,$$\sum_{k=m}^{n}\sqrt[k]{x} \leq C\bigg(\frac{m^2 \cdot \sqrt[m-1]{x}}{\log{x}} + n\bigg)$$

#### my attempt(wothless)

**Lemma 1:** For any real number $x > 1$,
$$\sqrt[k]{x} \leq 1 + \frac{\log{x}}{k}$$

**Lemma 2:** For any positive integers $m$ and $n$,
$$\frac{m^2}{2} \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$

**Proof of Lemma 1:**

By AM-GM,
$$\sqrt[k]{x} = \left( x^{1/k} \right)^k \leq \frac{1}{k} \left( x + \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k} + \dots + \frac{1}{k} \right) = 1 + \frac{\log{x}}{k}$$

**Proof of Lemma 2:**

By AM-GM,
$$\frac{m + m + \dots + m}{n} \leq \left( \frac{m}{n} \right)^{n}$$

Multiplying both sides by $\frac{n}{2}$,
$$\frac{m^2}{2} \leq \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m}^{n} \sqrt[k]{x} &\leq \sum_{k=m}^{n} \left( 1 + \frac{\log{x}}{k} \right) \\
&= n + \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{\log{x}}{k} \\
&= n + \log{x} \cdot \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \\
&\leq n + \log{x} \cdot \frac{m^2}{2} \\
&= C \left( \frac{m^2 \sqrt[m-1]{x}}{\log{x}} + n \right)
\end{align*}